# How to install libprotobuf.so.7 on ubuntu 20.04 machine?

Tags: apt, software-installation, shared-library

I see this message while running a program.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf.so.7: cannot open shared object file:
```

How can I install libprotobuf.so.7?

I'm on ubuntu 20.04. I tried `apt-file libprotobuf.so.7` but it gives me nothing. I tried `sudo apt install libprotobuf7` or for `libprotobuf-c` and it cannot locate the package.
How can I do that?

My OS version :

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

**ADD :**
I found these files already installed in my system.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17.0.0
```

so linked `/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so.7` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so`. (`/usr/local/lib2 is in` LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). But when I execute the program I see :

```
cm7_tarmac_decode: error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf.so.7: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

I figure this libprotobuf.so.17 is for x86_64 machine when the program (cm7_tarmac_decode) is looking for a 32 bit version.

so using `apt-cache search protobuf` I thought libprotobuf17 is my package and because it should be for 32 bit , I tried `sudo apt install libprotobuf17:i386` and it installed some files.
`dpkg libprotobuf17:i386` shows these installed files.

```
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17.0.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf17
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf17/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf17/copyright
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17
```

So under /usr/lib32, I did

```
/usr/lib32$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17 libprotobuf.so.7
```

(faking version 17 is version 7).
But when I excute the program I got this error message.

```
cm7_tarmac_decode: symbol lookup error: cm7_tarmac_decode: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal12kEmptyStringE
```

This means the libprotobuf.so.17 doesn't have the symbol `_ZN6google8protobuf8internal12kEmptyStringE` which is in real libprotobuf.so.7 file.
I tried `sudo apt install libprotobuf7:i386` but there is no such package.

**ADD2 :**
see Tooster's answer below. but before seeing that answer, I received libprotobuf.so.7 file from my colleague and used it.

Comment: What are you trying to do when you see this message?

Comment: When you install a package it contains lots of files. A file with a name like libprotobuf.so.7 is likely to be one of those files. If you really need to install something to provide that file then you need to find the package that contains it. Usually it will be a dependency of what ever you are using that results in the error you are having. On Arch Linux there is a package called protobuf so there may be something similar in the Ubuntu repositories

Comment: What package are you using when you get this error? Where did you get this package? What are you trying to do? If you reinstall the package you are using and it comes from the Ubuntu repositories it may fix the dependencies. If it came from somewhere else check for any installation instructions and in particular any info about dependencies

Comment: I think it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). First, like Pilot6 said, explain what are you trying to do with that, because this smells of bad assumptions and erroneously self-diagnosed problem. [Here is something related to your problem](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka001290/latest), but I didn't find other references about what `cm7_tarmac_decode` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an attempt at answering based on little info in the web:

Based on [this thread (a note in the middle about requiring protocol buffers 2.4.1)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka001290/latest#:%7E:text=Tarmac%20logging%20is,your%20shell%20environment.) as well as [this thread](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka005210/latest) You can try installing protobufs in the version 2.4.1 for 32 bits and later use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to set path to the installed buffers, for example using something similar to (note that it's temporary):

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /arm/tools/google/protobuf/2.4.1/rhe5-x86_32/lib:/arm/tools/google/protobuf/2.4.1/rhe5-x86_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or whatever path you will install that at. For more info you could try going to [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka002171/1-0) or [this](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka005210/latest) thread.

Comment: Hi I didn't know arm provided such information about protobuf 2.4.1 (which generates libprotubuf.so.7?). Yestereday, I received libprotobuf.so.7 file from my colleague and was able to use the cm7_tarmac_decode program while simulation. Thanks!